# Excel VBA to filter multiple columns but only 1 criteria

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter, advanced-filter

So I have 4 columns and thousands of rows.
I want to look for one word that appears either in column 3 OR 4 and get rid of the rest.
So filtering doesn't appear to work as I apply the filter in one column and this hides any row where the word doesn't exist, but it may exist in the next column.

I have tried:

```vb
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$D$" & lr)

AutoFilter Field:=3, Criterial:="Test1" or AutoFilter Field:=4, Criterial:="Test1"

End With
```

So I suspect it will need something more clever.

Comment: A common trick is to use a helper column with a formula like `=OR(C1="Test1",D1="Test1")` and filter on that.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? You could also use Advanced Filter

Comment: It needs to be VBA as I'll be calling on it using powershell

Comment: @BigBen How does that apply to every row?

Comment: Enter in cell E1 and drag down? Btw you can use Advanced Filter in VBA.

Comment: Roughly what % of rows are to be deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filter Data Using `AdvancedFilter`

**Formula in `Sheet2!E2`**

```
=OR(Sheet1!C2="Test1",Sheet1!D2="Test1")
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Sub FilterData()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source Range
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Criteria Range
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = cws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Filter.
    srg.AdvancedFilter xlFilterInPlace, crg

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - clear and concise! Appreciated.